# Display Scaling - Win 8 Control Panel

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, scaling

In "Control panel -> Display" there is the setting "Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays" which I disabled because i want the scaling in some monitors to be 100% (i have 2 low dpi monitors) and one to be 150%... my question is, does this really work? where can i set which display is to be small and which is large?!?!

Edit1: in screen resolution, when i click "Identify" the numbers "2" and "3" appear in the same display lol

Answer (score 0):

There's no way currently to set different scalings manually. You can set the "for all my displays" or have Windows choose the scaling based on what you set in the slider and the monitor resolution.